# Why is the type of stat.st_size not unsigned int?

Tags: gcc, system-calls, stat

I was trying to rely on the `stat(2)` system-call to determine the size of a file in order to allocate an appropriate buffer for it. More specifically I was using the `stat.st_size` of the structure that the system call fills.

But during debugging, I noticed that a large enough file causes some trouble: the `struct stat` as defined in the man pages looks like this:

```
struct stat {
    // ... 
    off_t     st_size;    /* total size, in bytes */
    // ... 
};
```

Where `st_size` is defined as `off_t` which resolves to a `long int` and to my surprise, not an `unsigned long int`.
This of course leads to a problem where a large enough file overflows the integer and causes the value to represent a negative number, which I did not account for in my checks (why would `st_size` be negative?)

Also, according to the man page, the system call should return an `EOVERFLOW` error when the number of blocks cannot be represented in `off_t`, but in my local ubuntu with gcc 9.3 - a file of size larger than `0x80000000` bytes raises no such error.
Also, the "correct" way is to compile with `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` which would extend the `off_t` field from a 32 bit integer to a 64 bit one which could help you manage larger files.

This of course solved my problem yet I was still wondering, why keep the definition as a signed integer?

Comment: Why should  0x80000000 bytes raise an error -- that's just 32 bits. Even if you are on a 32-bit Ubuntu, long int should be 64-bit.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant: A long is 32 bits on 32 bit systems.

Comment: @OskarSkog OP mentions "local ubuntu" with no further system details -- just some hand-waving. Not clear what you would recompile to apply that -D option -- own code, or the whole of kernel/GNU? And does a 32-bit system support files that big, and on which file systems? A sign bit is probably the least of it. And then we are going to allocate a buffer for the complete file contents too? We are rubbing too many limits here.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant it’s documented in `man 2 stat` — the application needs to be compiled with `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64`, and the C library and kernel need to support `sys_stat64` (since kernel 2.4). 0x80000000 doesn’t fit in a signed 32-bit integer.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant as for your other questions, they’re certainly valid, and they explain why distros can’t rebuild packages with `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` without checking things afterwards. However when writing an application that shouldn’t be much of a problem since the constraints can be taken into account from the start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`off_t` is [defined by POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_types.h.html), and is

> Used for file sizes.

It needs to be able to represent negative values because it isn’t only used for file sizes, it’s also used for file offsets (hence the name), and offsets can be negative (to move back in a file with [`lseek`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/lseek.html) for example).

You might wonder why `size_t` couldn’t be used instead; but that’s used to measure sizes of objects, C objects in particular, and not file sizes.

Comment: Which makes it all even more confusing, why use offset as the type for file sizes? If `size_t` wouldn't be right for it, isn't there any other type which is not a signed integer to take that place?

Comment: It’s not “offset”, it’s “file size”, and also offset — the definition is “file sizes”. I haven’t looked up the history of `off_t`, I’ll do that. As for there being another type, another one could be defined, but if you look at `sys/types.h` you’ll see that many types which could be unsigned are left signed so that negative values can be used to indicate errors...